# The largest interval over which the general solution of ODE is defined

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

This is a problem of section 2.3 of Engineering mathematics of Zill 7th international edition.

The problem is that "Find the general solution of the given differential equation and give the largest interval over which the general solution is defined." That's all written in problem.

My question is how to find the largest interval.
For example, for $$ydx-4(x+y^6)dy=0,$$ I can find the general solution and note that it is linear.

The answer sheet says that the largest interval is $0<y<\infty$.
I think that $y=0$ is impossible because in the process of finding solution we would work with $1/y$. But is it possible to choose $-\infty<y<0$?

Similarly, for $$(x^2 -1)dy/dx +2y=(x+1)^2,$$ can the largest interval be both $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1, \infty)$?

Comment: You need to typeset your work using Latex; see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm sorry for not using LaTeX. I'm not unfamiliar yet and this is urgent question. Also I thought that this question does not contain much formula.

Comment: 1) It is linear as equation for $x(y)$. Horizontal asymptotes there are poles for solutions $y(x)$. 2) Or it could be $(-1,1)$, depending on the location of the initial point.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your answering and editing!